# R - Similar records in different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, data-manipulation, querying

I wanna every records from a data frame where first 3 attributes, of each record, are equal to same 3 attributes from a record in another data frame.

For example, I have:

```
   File, Paragraph, Sentence, E, ED
   1.txt, 1, 1, CM, C.M.
   1.txt, 1, 1, LF, L.F.
   1.txt, 2, 1, E, E.
   1.txt, 2, 1, M, M.
   1.txt, 4, 1, LF, L.F.
   1.txt, 4, 1, NM, N.M.
   1.txt, 6, 1, RN, R.N.
   1.txt, 7, 1, AO, A.O.
```

And I have this data frame with 3 common columns, but less lines.

```
   File Paragraph Sentence occurrences
   1.txt        1        1           2
   1.txt        2        1           2
   1.txt        4        1           2
```

It's suppose to get something like this:

```
   File, Paragraph, Sentence, E, ED
   1.txt, 1, 1, CM, C.M.
   1.txt, 1, 1, LF, L.F.
   1.txt, 2, 1, E, E.
   1.txt, 2, 1, M, M.
   1.txt, 4, 1, LF, L.F.
   1.txt, 4, 1, NM, N.M.
```

How I can do it efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using merge. Something like that:

```
merge(x = first_data_frame, y = second_data_frame)
```

This would merge them, basically like JOIN (finds intersection) in SQL and should only keep records that have same file, paragraph, sentence. Then you can take out extra column "occurences". You can read more on merge [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).
You can control by which columns to merge by using:

```
merge(x = first_data_frame, y = second_data_frame, by=c("File", "Paragraph", "Sentence"))
```

Comment: Before I already was trying use `merge()`, but without parameter `by`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `subset()` with the `%in%` operator.

```
subset(df, Paragraph %in% df1$Paragraph) # Assuming Paragraph is numeric in both
#    File Paragraph Sentence  E.   ED
#1 1.txt,         1       1, CM, C.M.
#2 1.txt,         1       1, LF, L.F.
#3 1.txt,         2       1,  E,   E.
#4 1.txt,         2       1,  M,   M.
#5 1.txt,         4       1, LF, L.F.
#6 1.txt,         4       1, NM, N.M.
```

Comment: Of course data frames are samples. So I have different combinations of files, paragraphs and sentences.
I tried `subset(df, File %in% df1$File & Paragraph %in% df1$Paragraph & Sentence %in% df1$Sentence)` but without success.
I don't know nevertheless if it's possible using `subset()`. I can get it with `merge()`, as suggested by @Zakkery.